# How to control action attribute of a form depending on condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I'm having a form in PHP. For now I've defined hard coded value in it's action attribute. Now the scenario is I'm calling a JavaScript function on form submit. In that function I've used `confirm()` function.

Depending on the value of confirm i.e. true or false I want to submit the form to subsequent page. In short I want to submit the form to any of the two PHP pages depending on a output value of `confirm()`.

If you want I can provide you my code.

Comment: $("#form_id").attr("action", "anywhere.php");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could use jQuery to override the submit function:

```
var sendURL = "send/to/url.php"

$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    // get all the inputs into an array.
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

    var sendData = "";
    $inputs.each(function() {
        sendData += this.name + "=" + $(this).val();
    });

    //confimation
    var conf = confirm("hello world");

    if(conf){
        sendURL="send/to/url/1.php";
    } else {
        sendURL="send/to/url/2.php";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: sendURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: sendData,
        success: function (data) {
           //do stuff when ajax succeeds
        }
    });
});
```

change the sendURL variable to whatever you like in your javascript code...